# Processing: UnsatisfiedLinkError when running getPortIdentifiers();

Tags: java, serial-port, processing

I'm adapting [this sketch](http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/66707) for use with a serial based thermal printer.

While declaring an object, a connect function is run, and specifically the

`Enumeration<?> portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();`

is generating this error:

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver`

Here's the start of the connect function:

```
 private void connect() {


                    CommPortIdentifier portId = null;


        Enumeration<?> portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        // iterate through, looking for the port
        while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
          CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
          for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
            if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
              portId = currPortId;
              break;
            }
          }
        }


        if (portId == null) {
          System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
          return;
        }
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I've researched the error message, and the only results that come up imply a 32-bit issue, which seems to have been resolved many versions of Processing ago. Other solutions people have suggestion have been specific to the Windows and Linux platforms.

I'm on a Mac running 64-bit Processing.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it. The serial processing library comes with `libjSSC-2.6.jnilib` and this older library was looking for `librxtxSerial.jnilib`, which I grabbed [here](http://blog.iharder.net/2009/08/18/rxtx-java-6-and-librxtxserial-jnilib-on-intel-mac-os-x/).